# How can I put a button that only shows at specific page on PageView? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm creating a PageView with a total of 4 pages. I wanna put a "Next" button that'll move the user to the login page but the button only shows at the 4th page at the bottom right corner and without changing the position of the content of 4th page. How can i do that?

Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/login_view/login_view.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/onboarding_view/onboarding_page.dart';

class OnBoardingView extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget nextButton() {
      return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginView(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Text('Next'),
      );
    }

    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return PageView(
      pageSnapping: true,
      controller: controller,
      children: [
        OnBoardingPage(
            image: 'assets/deliciousfood.png',
            title: 'Delicious Food',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum'),
        OnBoardingPage(
            image: 'assets/fastshipping.png',
            title: 'Fast Shipping',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum'),
        OnBoardingPage(
            image: 'assets/certificatefood.png',
            title: 'Certificate Food',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum'),
        OnBoardingPage(
            image: 'assets/paymentonline.png',
            title: 'Payment Online',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Stack widget on the last page with children as,
`OnBoardingPage` + `Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, child: nextButton)`;

For Example:

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        title: const Text("S.O Playground"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "OnBoarding Page Details.",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('Next'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thx, this solves my problem. but if someday I wanna add another page with another content at the last page, is there any other way that's more efficient?
because, if that's the case, I have to move the Stack code to the last page.

Comment: You can create a separate widget with a child and an onPressed listener parameters and use it as the last page.

Comment: how can I do that?